# file_get_contents for file owned by root

Tags: php, file-permissions, file-get-contents

I am in the process of setting up a remote backup for my MariaDB server (running on 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04).

The first step in this process was easy - I am using [automysqlbackup](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-backup-mysql-databases-on-an-ubuntu-vps) as explained here.
The next step is mostly pretty easy - I am uploading the latest backup in the folder */var/lib/automysqlbackup/daily/dbname* to a remote backup service (EVBackup in the present case) via SFTP.  The only issue I have run into is this

The files created in that folder by automysqlbackup bear names in the format **dbname_2014-04-25_06h47m.Friday.sql.gz** and are owned by root.  Establishing the name of the latest backup file is not an issue.  However, once I have got it I am unable to use file_get_contents since it is owned by the *root* user and has its permissions set to 600.  Perhaps there is a way to run a shell script that fetches me those contents?  I am a novice when it comes to shell scripts.  I'd be much obliged to anyone who might be able to suggest a way to get at the backup data from PHP.

Comment: automysqlbackup supports post backup scripts. Why don't you add a script that chmods the backup files? Or just place the upload in that script too, one thing less to worry about.

Comment: Thanks.  You put me on the right track here.  Thinking about it using PHP, reading the backup with file_get_contents is a recipe for disaster since the backup size may well be too big for PHP to handle.  I am a newbie when it comes to writing shell scripts so it has taken me the best part of 4h to write something that is working but I am getting there :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone running into this thread I give below the fully functional script I created.  It assumes that you have created and shared your public ssh_key with the remote server (EVBackup in my case) as described [here](http://www.evbackup.com/support-rsync-scripting-automation/).

In my case I had to deal with one additional complication - I am in the process of setting up the first of my servers but will have several others.  Their domain names bear the form svN.example.com where N is 1, 2, 3 etc.

On my EVBackup account I have created folders bearing the same names, sv1, sv2 etc.  I wanted to create a script that would safely run from any of my servers.  Here is that script with some comments

```
#! /bin/bash
# Backup to EVBackup Server

local="/var/lib/automysqlbackup/daily/dbname"
#replace dbname as appropriate

svr="$(uname -n)"
remote="$(svr/.example.com/)"
#strip out the .example.com bit to get the destination folder on the remote server
remote+="/"

evb="user@user.evbackup.com:"
#user will have to be replaced with your username
evb+=$remote

cmd='rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /backup/ssh_key" '
#your ssh key location may well be different

cmd+=$local
cmd+=$evb
#at this point cmd will be something like
#rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /backup/ssh_key" /home bob@bob.evbackup.com:home-data

eval $cmd
```

Comment: Some very useful tips for [putting commands in variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and [quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). There's no need for `eval`.