# Send shell script eval results by email

Tags: shell, email, rsync

This question follows on from my own answer to one of my [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287291/file-get-contents-for-file-owned-by-root/23292969#23292969).  The script I have given there works just fine.  To round things off I would like to grab the results of the *eval'd* rsync results and email them off.  I haven't got the foggiest idea how that should be done.

### Update

In response to the comments I am providing more details in this question.  The script in question copied over from my own answer to my other question:

```
#! /bin/bash
# Backup to EVBackup Server

local="/var/lib/automysqlbackup/daily/dbname"
#replace dbname as appropriate

svr="$(uname -n)"
remote="$(svr/.example.com/)"
#strip out the .example.com bit to get the destination folder on the remote server
remote+="/"

evb="user@user.evbackup.com:"
#user will have to be replaced with your username
evb+=$remote

cmd='rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /backup/ssh_key" '
#your ssh key location may well be different

cmd+=$local
cmd+=$evb
#at this point cmd will be something like
#rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /backup/ssh_key" /home bob@bob.evbackup.com:home-data

eval $cmd
```

When you run this script from the terminal you see the output from the Rsync command.  What I would like to be able to do is to grab that output into a shell variable and then send it off by email so I can keep a human aware of any issues that might have been encountered whilst doing the Rsync.

I guess I will be able to figure out how to send emails from a shell script.  What has me stumped is how I capture the payload for that email - i.e. the Rsync output.

Comment: Please include the relevant details here.

Comment: Are you asking how to send emails on the shell in general, or how to do things like escaping, MIME types and compression?